# Permission denied for many directories with Rsync

Tags: server, permissions, backup, rsync

I'm using Rsync to backup an Ubuntu Server server. I'm getting a lot of permission denied messages. Is there a command I can use to see exactly what directories were denied? I could scroll back up through all the files, but that would take forever. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you have asked the same question on server fault http://serverfault.com/questions/345605/permission-denied-for-many-directories-with-rsync .There some user have given good solution for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll need a bit more details.
When are permissions denied and what do you want to achieve?

If I presumed right and it's denied when you try to upload files I would presume you can allow permissions to an RSync group to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems as if access is denied because I do not have root access on the server being backed up. I am using the following command: sudo rsync -av ubuntu@*******:/ /media/backup1/ubuntubackup. I figured out how to see where access was denied. Now, I am wondering how to get root access to my Ubuntu Server server, via Rsync. Once I log in through Rsync, I do not have the option to issue a sudo command. I understand that I can configure the Rsync daemon, instead of going through SSH, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it through SSH with Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not an Rsync expert but it looks like the -e "ssh -l root" parameter from the other suggestion does that.